# How to run openssl command from JAVA using Runtime?

Tags: java, openssl

I want to read private and public key generated using PuttyGen for that I used openssl to convert them into DER format.

```
String[] execStr = {"openssl","pkcs8", "-topk8", "-inform", "PEM", "-outform","DER", "-in", "src\\srcData\\openssh1\\privateKey.pem","-out", "src\\srcData\\openssh1\\privateKey.der" };

File execDir = new File("C:\\openssl-1.0.2d-fips-2.0.10\\bin");

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execStr,null,execDir);
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "openssl" (in directory "C:\openssl-1.0.2d-fips-2.0.10\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1059)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:631)
    at PrivateKeyReader.get(PrivateKeyReader.java:21)
    at Test1.main(Test1.java:50)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:455)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:151)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1040)
    ... 3 more
```

Here I am not able figure out the exact issue, please let me know if anyone know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you downloaded the Windows version of `openssl-1.0.2d-fips-2.0.10`. The executable contained in the bin folder is called `openssl.exe`, not `openssl`. For this reason, you get the error `The system cannot find the file specified`. Your `execStr` should therefore be `String[] execStr = {"openssl.exe", ...`

To prevent this issue in the future, you can make Windows Explorer show the full `openssl.exe` name instead of `openssl`, using the instructions [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/in-win10-how-to-show-the-file-extension-for/ed21ff20-cdb3-4263-9c7d-fc6ed125fc82).

Also note that when you use `C:\\openssl-1.0.2d-fips-2.0.10\\bin` as the `execDir`, the path `src\\srcData\\openssh1\\privateKey.pem` is interpreted relative to `execDir`. You should therefore turn it into an absolute path using:

```
File inputFile = new File("src\\srcData\\openssh1\\privateKey.pem");

String[] execStr = {"openssl.exe ", ..., "-in", inputFile.getCanonicalPath(), ... };
```

The same also applies to the output file.